# Converting Images with High DPI and Low Pixels to Low DPI and High Pixels

Tags: photoshop, resolution

I'm currently in the process of making an interactive map. From previous knowledge I learned that it was all about pixel count so that the map could cover a large area. This map needs to cover an area twice the size of the Earth.

My original map is at `35000 x 20000 pixels @ 300 dpi`. Which gives me great zoomability for the interactive map.

However, I was just contacted by an artist that offered to make the map. And they suggested a size of `9000 x 6000 pixels but at 1200 dpi`. Saying that this can be resized up to my original needs without the loss of quality.

My issue here is that I don't understand how that could work. And so, I don't want to start the job and paying for it. Until I'm sure that the end result will be as by my needs.

PS: I do not know if this is the right stackoverflow to be asking this question. And looking at the "Similar Questions" in the right pane, suggest it isn't. If that is true, perhaps somebody can point me in the right direction.

Comment: The surface area of the Earth is 510,000,000 km2, so if we assume sides in the approximate ratio of your pixel counts that makes 30,000km x 17,000km. So taking the short side, according to your artist, you would have 6,000 pixels to represent 17,000 km. So each pixel will correspond to 3km on the ground. Except it will be worse by a factor of 1.4 if the map is twice the area of the Earth, so each pixel will be around 4.2km. So you will be able to just make out features that are of the order of 10+km by 10+km in size as a group of 4 pixels.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't explain properbly. Saying it is twice the size of Earth was an example. This is for a fantasy map. And using the features of MapTiler (software), once you zoom far enough in on an area it will change the map/image to one of that specific area. Such as going from World>Region>Country>City.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This obviously won't work: DPI matters only for printing. So 9000x6000 in whatever DPI will have to be scaled up to 35000x20000 with loss of quality. Maybe the artist meant something else..?

And the proper stack exchange for this question would be a https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com